# Feathers and Sequelize SQL Server Errors

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I'm running into several sql server errors, trying to get started with a simple rest api using feathers js and sequelize. I am using SQL Server 2012 (express) version.

First my code:

```
const { db } = require('../database');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const service = require('feathers-sequelize');
const app = require('../app');

const Model = db.define('workorder', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
  created_by: Sequelize.STRING,
  modified_by: Sequelize.STRING,

  status_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  date_completed: Sequelize.DATE,
  category: Sequelize.STRING,
  location: Sequelize.STRING,
  details: Sequelize.TEXT,
  crew_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  assigned_to: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
  schema: 'dbo',
  freezeTableName: true,
  createdAt: 'date_created',
  updatedAt: 'date_modified',
});

app.use('/api/workorders', service({
  Model,
  id: 'id',
  paginate: {
    default: 10,
    max: 100,
  },
}));
```

When I hit the api endpoint `/api/workorders` it errors out:

SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

I see that the sql generated:

```
 Executing (default): SELECT [id], [created_by], [modified_by], [status_name], [date_completed], [category], [location], [details], [crew_name], [assigned_to], [date_created], [date_modified] FROM [dbo].[workorder] AS [workorder] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

It seems that sql server requires some ORDER BY clause. So I tried sending a parameter to the endpoint `/api/workorders?$sort=id`

This also errors out:

SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name '1'.

The SQL Generated looks like this:

```
Executing (default): SELECT [id], [created_by], [modified_by], [status_name], [date_completed], [category], [location], [details], [crew_name], [assigned_to], [date_created], [date_modified] FROM [dbo].[workorder] AS [workorder] ORDER BY [workorder].[0] DESC, [workorder].[1] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

This error is more obvious, there are no columns 1 or 0.

Anyone run into these issues before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an incompatibility of Sequelize with older versions of MSSQL server as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD/issues/85). A Feathers specific solution mentioned [in this issue comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4404#issuecomment-278537449) to add `$sort` and `$limit` like this:

```
query: {
        $limit: 5,
        $sort: {createdAt: -1}
      }
```

Comment: Okay, I think that issue mentions sql server 2008. 2012 (which is what I'm using) supports FETCH. So I just need to add the `$sort` parameter each time I send a query is what I'm seeing. But it seems like there's some deeper issues when dealing with sorting, since Sequelize is trying to select columns 0 and 1 which don't exist. Is there a better supported orm in feathers for sql server that you know of?

Comment: I believe KneJS (`feathers-knex`) supports MSSQL as well. There might also be a bug in the `feathers-sequelize` adapter but I don't think it's doing anything out of the ordinary. Unfortunatly we don't have an easy way to test this with MSSQL.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Unfortunately we're stuck with sql server due to some other software dependencies. I'll look into other feathers integrations (knex) to try out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As referenced by Daff I too found that for SQL Server 2014, Sequelize still did not generate MSSQL 2014 compatible code.  So, given the suggestion [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4404#issuecomment-278939026) to specify a version of MSSQL less than 11.0.0, I specified somewhat arbitrarily a database version of 10.0.0.

This worked for me - Sequelize now generates 2014 (and earlier) compatible tsql code.  I made the change to the databaseVersion property in the options object passed when producing the Sequelize instance in the 'sequelize.js' file, generated from the feathers-cli, as follows:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  dialect: 'mssql',
  host: hostname,
  logging: console.log,
  define: {
    freezeTableName: true
  },
  // from https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4404
  // use earlier SQL Server version to assure tsql compatible code generation
  databaseVersion: '10.0.0' 
});
```